# Windows IoT Remote Client tool not connecting

Tags: azure, iot

I want to use the Windows IoT Remote Client tool to connect to my Raspberry Pi 2 but I'm not able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running a build that actually supports this feature. You can easily check this by looking in the Device Portal. If the last menu tab is called 'Remote' you have a build that support this feature.

You also need to enable this feature using the same menu tab.